# How to add a variable with a URL inside of an if statement

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Here is the code I wrote.  The else is working.  The if URL's are not.

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo'<a href="$adminurl;" class="btn btn-primary">Set As Facebook Cover</a>';
    echo'<a href="$img[0];" class="btn btn-default">Download</a>';
} else {
    echo'<a href="http://domain.com/register/" class="btn btn-primary">Set As Facebook Cover</a>';
    echo '<a href="http://domain.com/register/" class="btn btn-default">Download</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: quwhat is the value of $img[0]?

Comment: $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), "fbcover-large");

Comment: so, you want to anchor  the text "Download" to the image path?

Answer (score 0):

To include a variable in a string, the string needs to be wrapped in double quotes, like

```
echo "This is a $var";
```

not `echo 'This is a $var';`

Or you can use the `.` to concat the strings:

```
echo 'This is a ' . $var;
```

Try this:

```
echo'<a href="' . $adminurl . '" class="btn btn-primary">Set As Facebook Cover</a>';
echo'<a href="' . $img[0] . '" class="btn btn-default">Download</a>';
```

Final note, there is no need to use the `;` after the variables because you are not ending the statement.

[**See a demo**](http://codepad.org/s0lRrIaB)